# Compiler-dependent OpenMP min/max reduction pragma

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp

My C++ code uses OpenMP directives and needs to compile with GCC and Visual Studio 2019.
OpenMP min/max reduction operators were introduced in OpenMP 3.1, but Visual Studio 2019 [only supports OpenMP 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58453129/150884).

I'd like my code to revert to a serial loop under Visual Studio, but I understand that [the preprocessor cannot represent a conditional pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1135822/150884) like this:

```cpp
// invalid use of preprocessor:
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define OMP_MIN(expr)
#else
#define OMP_MIN(expr) #pragma omp parallel for reduction(min:(expr))
#endif

double x = 10.0;

OMP_MIN(x)
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    x = fmin(x, array[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try to extract the loop part in two different functions (serial loob, OpenMP loop) and describe your define according to these two functions

Comment: That's true, but it'll need lots of refactoring to avoid duplicating code since I have several of these loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_Pragma()` from C++11 to have a function-like macro that conditionally enables a pragma:

```
#include <cmath>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define OMP_MINX()
#else
#define OMP_MINX() _Pragma("omp parallel for reduction(min:x)")
#endif

int main() {
  double x = 10.0;
  double array[50];
  int array_size = 50;

  OMP_MINX()
  for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    x = std::fmin(x, array[i]);
  }
}
```

but I haven't figured out how to make gcc accept anything other than a literal string for the argument to allow using an arbitrary variable - not even the preprocessor's stringification operator works, meaning you might as well just use

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min:x)
#endif
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
  x = std::fmin(x, array[i]);
}
```

Comment: `_Pragma()` is new to me, I wonder if it was added to address this type of use case?  I can't find much info about it.  Anyway, I've gone with your second alternative, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DO_PRAGMA()` macro idiom explained in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html.

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define OMP_MINX(expr)
#else
#define OMP_MINX(expr) DO_PRAGMA(omp parallel for reduction(min: expr))
#endif
```

`OMP_MINX(x)` expands to the desired `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min: x)` if `_MSC_VER` is not defined. `expr` is expanded first and afterwards the whole argument of `DO_PRAGMA()` is stringified before the `_Pragma()` operator is applied. This is what OP asked for.

Solution is inspired from this answer:
[How to concatenate strings in the arguments of _Pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762357/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-the-arguments-of-pragma)